# What tense should I use to describe something that could be true, and is true?

Tags: grammar, tenses

> haha, that is what I was going to say, then I figure someone would have already thought that line. Dang!

context: I am surveying Quora home feed and saw an interesting comment. The above sentence is my response. Well, then I start to have the feeling that I used the wrong tense of "think". I am not sure what is the grammatically correct way to say the above sentence. thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything that is true is automatically something that could be true; necessarily true entails possibly true. Everything about your sentence is grammatically OK, except: (a) _that is_ => _that's_; (b) _figure_ => _figured_; (c) _thought that line_ => _thought of that line_. No tense problems at all.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Why's there the need to contract "that is" to "that's"?

Comment: Because in English speech it normally is. It's optional but almost inevitable at normal conversational speeds, and its absence will likely be interpreted as emphasis, hesitation, foreignness, stiffness, or some other potentially distracting perception. When in Rome, talk like the Romans do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did the figuring in the past (at about the same time as you were going to say something), you should use the past tense:

> That is what I was going to say, then I *figured* someone would have already thought that line.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, shorter:

*Ha, ha. I was going to say that, and **wouldn't be the first** [**either**].*

Removing "think/figure" makes the sentence more direct.

Tenses, as Professor Lawler says, are fine.

Comment: I don't think that's answering the question.

Comment: There's a lack of connection between the title and the body of the OP message. That's the best I was able to do under the circumstances.